# Multiple bootstrap code is observed in Angular

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-5, ng-bootstrap

I have an angular application, I am using Bootstrap classes. Whenever I am adding a new component like nav, button, etc. I am not able to see exact color and properties whatever I see in the bootstrap documentation, for eg: if I add a button HTML and added btn and btn-primary classes then I am not getting the exact color which is specified in bootstrap documentation:

[Primary button in my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JWUn.png)

[Primary button from bootstrap documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ig8fY.png)

In the inspect page I can see like this:
[Inspect page for button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADt0j.png)

Could someone please help me on this

Comment: Please create a reproduction on stackblitz, or share your code

Comment: sorry I can't share my code, how to create a reproduction, that I don't know, how I can reproduce it in a new project

Comment: Well it seems like in your buttons.scss line 60 there is an override to the .btn-primary class with the color you see in your application. If you remove this then you will get the original bootstrap color

Comment: buttons.scss is from bootstrap only, those are not implemented by myself